# How Safe UI creates new Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am creating a frontend similar to [Safe UI](https://gnosis-safe.io/app/welcome) using which users can create new multi-sig wallets for themselves. I am using [Safe Core SDK](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk) on my front end (Next.js). Now when I [deploy the new safe](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#2-deploy-a-new-safe) I face the following [issue](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/128). Now I am wondering what different Safe UI do to create the new safe for the users. So after spending some time with their front end [repo](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react) it seems to me that their code does not directly call the `deploySafe` function and do many things in order. Although I am not able to get it properly what the code is actually doing.

Can someone guide me on how to create a front end app similar to Safe UI and have a smooth safe creation flow?

Comment: We created the Safe UI way before safe-core-sdk was a thing. Now the recommended way to create a safe is the core-sdk package. We will investigate the issue after the team is back from the holidays.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Hey @mikheevm, may I know when will this issue of deploying safe get resolved as it is a blocker in our product development for the past 2 weeks?